# Is this a safe way to use Async with events

Tags: winforms, async-await

I've previously used the Task Parallel Library to keep the UI thread responsive, but I'm trying to switch to async/await to simplify the code. The project I'm working on is in WinForms. There is a presentation layer that communicates with view interfaces, and an assembly that contains winforms forms that implement these interfaces, with dependency injection binding everything together. In the specific example below, the form has a menu/button/etc that sends a request to the presentation layer for new data. I've ignored exception handling to keep the example simple.

In the form code we have an event handler like this:

```
private async sub DataRequest(sender as object, e as EventArgs) handles SomeButton.click
        Dim etask = New Threading.Tasks.Task(Sub() RaiseEvent DataRefreshRequest(Me, EventArgs.Empty))
        etask.Start()
        Await etask
end sub
```

Not sure if there's a neater way of awaiting an event being raised, the above seems a bit clumsy

The presentation layer responds to this event with code like this:

```
Private Async Sub HandleDataRequest() Handles _view.DataRefreshRequest
  Dim gdtask = New Tasks.Task(Of IEnumerable(Of Summary))(Function() GetDataTask())
  gdtask.Start()
  _view.Data = Await gdtask
End Sub
```

We are stuck with .Net 4 on this project so we are using Microsoft.BCL.Async. GetDataTask is effectively a Linq query on entities exposed by the business layer, but without .Net 4.5 we can't execute it using .ToListAsync

The bit I'm a little unsure of is the way I'm raising the event in the winforms assembly. Is that the right way to do it? It seems to work okay, but I'm concerned about any unforeseen problems of doing it this way. Better to do it right from the start then find there's a problem once this pattern is in common use.

Answer (score 2):

Using `Task.Run` is better than the `Task` constructor with `Task.Start`.

Other than that, I'd just recommend some comments. As you noted, the *ideal* solution would be to use `ToListAsync` and make it truly asynchronous, but that's not possible given your platform.

`Task.Run` is *normally* used for running CPU-bound code on a background thread, and this code is not CPU-bound. So I'd recommend a comment for your future self so that when you do upgrade to .NET 4.5, you can know those `Task.Run` calls are no longer necessary.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, that's reassuring. Task.Run would certainly tidy it up a bit.